# Why is Linq.Enumerable.Count() throwing `InvalidOperationException`

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Why it does not understand that an exception has occurred in this area.
I tested. However, it does not occur.

If modified as follows: Would it solve?

```
if (items != null && items.Count() > 0) >>> if(items.Any())
```

**Exception Message:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

**Exception Code:**

```
var items = this._dataManager.LotList
                  .Where(lot => lot.LOT_ID == (string)cpVals[6] && lot.ADDRESS.ToString() == (string)cpVals[3])
                      .OrderByDescending(lot => lot.CREATE_TIME);
if (items != null && items.Count() > 0)
{
```

**Testing Code:**

```
        List<User> Users = new List<User>();
        Users.Add(new User());
        Users[0].Name = "Kim";
        Users[0].Age = 1;
        Users.Add(new User());
        Users[1].Name = "Kim";
        Users[1].Age = 2;

        var items = Users.Where(u => u.Name == "Kim").OrderByDescending(u => u.Age);
        Users.Clear();
        if (items != null && items.Count()>0)
        {
            User a = items.ElementAt(0);
        }

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
```

Comment: Is it single thread application? I do not see how that exception can happens, unless some other thread modify `this._dataManager.LotList` while your busy in `.Count()`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us the right code. The problem is occurring because somewhere in your code you are modifying a collection while you are iterating it. None of the code you've shown does that so we can't say what's going on.

The only other thing I'll mention is in your testing code. You have written this:

```
    var items = Users.Where(u => u.Name == "Kim").OrderByDescending(u => u.Age);
    Users.Clear();
    if (items != null && items.Count()>0)
    {
        User a = items.ElementAt(0);
    }
```

It is very clear that `items != null` will always be `true`. You've definitely assigned it. However, because you issue a `Users.Clear()` call before you try to evaluate the items then `items.Count()` will **always be equal to zero**. LINQ uses deferred execution so the query is only evaluated at the point you use it.

Comment: You're right, that code just doesn't have the behavior he described.

Comment: Kinda sad that you have to write an answer that proves that the posted code is nonsense.  Still has nothing to do with an actual answer, who is helped by this??  Please VTC instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use items.Any() instead of items.Count() if you just want to know if the items has any things inside of it, but you still have to check for null first.

so:

```
if(items != null && items.Any()){ /* hooray goes here */}
```

Any() is way faster than Count() since it stops after checking the existence of one item.

Comment: Unless your Enumerable is a List, in which case Count() just returns the in-memory list size, while Any would get the iterator and move to the first element instead, which is more expensive.

Comment: @roim - Actually, more specifically speaking if your `IEnumerable<T>` also is an `ICollection<T>` then the `.Count()` extension method uses the collections `.Count()` method. It's not just a list.

Comment: More specifically, it returns the `Count` property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just write toList and the count this can do a trick for you 
enumerable.toList().count()

Comment: Yeah, this would trick the compiler by copying all query elements into a list. It misses the point though.